# Java bubble sort code problems

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Write a computer program that prompts the user for a number, creates an array for that number of random integers, and then uses the bubble sort to order the array. The program should print out the array prior to the call to the sorting algorithm and afterwards.

I have most of the bubble sort working, it is just the implementation of the random integers and user input for the size of the array that I can't seem to figure out.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Random;

    class Test
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
       int n, c, d, swap;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       Random r = new Random();

       System.out.println("enter number of elements to sort");
       n = r.nextInt();

       int array[] = new int[n];

       for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
       array[c] = r.nextInt();

        for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
          for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
           if (array[d] > array[d+1])        {
            swap       = array[d];
            array[d]   = array[d+1];
            array[d+1] = swap;
            }
           }
          }

      System.out.println("Sorted array :");

      for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
      System.out.println(array[c]);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Obvious homework is obvious.

Comment: It's just a typo. Change it to `n = in.nextInt();`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the scanner correctly. You should have `n = in.nextInt();`

Comment: The random is fine do not need to re-instantiate to generate new random ints

Comment: Answer edited. Sorry I do not know much of the `Random` object